# Correct way to set Exit Code of Process?

Tags: go

In Go what is the proper way to set the exit code of the process?

I tried changing main func to

```
func main() int {
    return -1
}
```

But this causes error `func main must have no arguments and no return values`

OK so there is `os.Exit(code int)`, however this immediately aborts the process and does not exit cleanly (no deferreds are run for example).

I also found that `panic` will exit process and set status code to nonzero, this may be the best way, although it dumps a stack trace to console.

What is the right way to set the exit code?

Comment: I also was wondering about the same thing. Maybe this thread can help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/tPOFzJkkof8. But it did not help me much.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make `os.Exit` the last deferred function executed. Deferred functions are executed immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the reverse order they were deferred. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    code := 0
    defer func() {
        os.Exit(code)
    }()
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Another deferred func")
    }()
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    code = 1
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, 世界
Another deferred func
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

Go Playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/o0LfisANwb

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Defer statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)
>
> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to
>   the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the
>   surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of
>   its function body, or because the corresponding goroutine is
>   panicking.
>
> DeferStmt = "defer" Expression .
>
> The expression must be a function or method call; it cannot be
>   parenthesized. Calls of built-in functions are restricted as for
>   expression statements.
>
> Each time the "defer" statement executes, the function value and
>   parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the
>   actual function body is not executed. Instead, deferred functions are
>   executed immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the
>   reverse order they were deferred.

Comment: Very nice! I didn't even fathom this as a possibility.