# How to exit a go program honoring deferred calls?

Tags: go, exit, defer-keyword

I need to use `defer` to free allocations manually created using `C` library, but I also need to `os.Exit` with non 0 status at some point. The tricky part is that `os.Exit` skips any deferred instruction:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {

    // `defer`s will _not_ be run when using `os.Exit`, so
    // this `fmt.Println` will never be called.
    defer fmt.Println("!")
    // sometimes ones might use defer to do critical operations
    // like close a database, remove a lock or free memory

    // Exit with status code.
    os.Exit(3)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/CDiAh9SXRM stolen from https://gobyexample.com/exit

So how to exit a go program honoring declared `defer` calls? Is there any alternative to `os.Exit`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601516/correct-way-to-set-exit-code-of-process

Comment: @ctcherry no success with defer `os.Exit`: http://play.golang.org/p/IsSI9VB7j8

Comment: reverse the defer order http://play.golang.org/p/a4RP5BiXbc

Comment: oh I see, that's a problem. In my case I can only defer `os.Exit` after running other operations that also defer something... let me think a little more.

Comment: `defer` in `main` combined with `os.Exit` is definitely a rough spot. Architecting around it like @Rob Napier does below is a better way to go.

Comment: Is this a suitable strategy? http://soniacodes.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/deferred-functions-and-an-exit-code/ At least it doesn't seem to force a code pattern.

Comment: `panic` is an exception, I don't think running defers and passing and error code should require that kind of maneuver. Keeping the defer out of main seems like a simpler and more idiomatic approach.

Comment: @ctcherry I ended up creating a response but thanks for the warning. I'll keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`runtime.Goexit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit) is the easy way to accomplish that.

> Goexit terminates the goroutine that calls it. No other goroutine is affected. **Goexit runs all deferred calls before terminating the goroutine.** Because Goexit is not panic, however, any recover calls in those deferred functions will return nil.

However:

> Calling Goexit from the main goroutine terminates that goroutine without func main returning. Since func main has not returned, the program continues execution of other goroutines. If all other goroutines exit, the program crashes.

So if you call it from the main goroutine, at the top of `main` you need to add

```
defer os.Exit(0)
```

Below that you might want to add some other `defer` statements that inform the other goroutines to stop and clean up.

Comment: I had no idea `runtime.Goexit()` existed. Is this from some recent release?

Comment: @marcio I did some digging in the Go repositories. I couldn't find exactly when it was introduced, but I did find [this test that references it and is "Copyright 2013"](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/53fd522c0db58f3bd75d85295f46bb06e8ab1a9b/test/fixedbugs/issue5963.go) from before you posted this question.

Comment: @marcio I did a little more digging and found [an archive of the documentation from 2009](http://web.archive.org/web/20091215044631/http://golang.org/pkg/runtime). Goexit is listed there.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the accepted answer. The other answers are definitely still valid, but this seems the simplest approach - for now :D

Answer (score 59):

Just move your program down a level and return your exit code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func doTheStuff() int {
    defer fmt.Println("!")

    return 3
}

func main() {
    os.Exit(doTheStuff())
}
```

Comment: So I shouldn't to use `defer` inside `func main` or any function that exits?

Comment: More to the point, I don't recommend using `os.Exit()` in random places in the code. It makes testing very difficult besides the problem of error codes. peterSO's solution that @ctcherry links is ok, but it doesn't scale well IMO to a larger program. You'd have to make the `code` global. I believe you should keep main() fairly simple, and have it just take care of the OS-level things (like the final status code).

Comment: Hi, I found a way to handle this without impose any architecture. Anyway, +1 because it's a good advice to always try KISS first.

Comment: https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#exit-once

Answer (score 34):

After some research, refer to this [this](http://soniacodes.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/deferred-functions-and-an-exit-code/), I found an alternative that:

- Doesn't impose a certain architecture like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629493/438563
- Doesn't require any global value like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601700/438563

We can take advantage of `panic` and `recover`. It turns out that `panic`, by nature, will honor `defer` calls but will also always exit with non `0` status code and dump a stack trace. The trick is that we can override last aspect of panic behavior with:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

type Exit struct{ Code int }

// exit code handler
func handleExit() {
    if e := recover(); e != nil {
        if exit, ok := e.(Exit); ok == true {
            os.Exit(exit.Code)
        }
        panic(e) // not an Exit, bubble up
    }
}
```

Now, to exit a program at any point and still preserve any declared `defer` instruction we just need to emit an `Exit` type:

```
func main() {
    defer handleExit() // plug the exit handler
    defer fmt.Println("cleaning...")
    panic(Exit{3}) // 3 is the exit code
}
```

It doesn't require any refactoring apart from plugging a line inside `func main`:

```
func main() {
    defer handleExit()
    // ready to go
}
```

This scales pretty well with larger code bases so I'll leave it available for scrutinization. Hope it helps.

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/4tyWwhcX0-

Comment: Best answer of the all so far! One question, how to deal with normal exit then? How to make sure the `handleExit` get called even with normal exit ? Ref: https://play.golang.org/p/QDJum4kOXk un-comment the `//panic` and see the difference.

Comment: I think a handle for a normal exit 0 event doesn't exist, but you can always panic(Exit{0}) and then handle it or maybe defer handleNormalExit() before anything else on main()?

Comment: Yes, this sounds more like the exceptions bubbling in java/C#

Answer (score 30):

For posterity, for me this was a more elegant solution:

```
func main() { 
    retcode := 0
    defer func() { os.Exit(retcode) }()
    defer defer1()
    defer defer2()

    [...]

    if err != nil {
        retcode = 1
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: This really takes the best parts of the other answers.

Comment: I was breaking my head exploring different ways around this issue; why os.exit does not also call the "defer" functions but in my case simply using "return" instead of os.exit solved the issue. Now I feel stupid I didnt think of it earlier

Comment: on a side note, does defer1, defer2 execute in chronological order?

Comment: @Macindows This is Go standard: last to first. So `defer2()`, then `defer1()`

Comment: This code will suppress panics. Also, if `retcode` is not changed (during a panic, for example), it will return always 0 (no erro). If you are sure your code is panic free, you are probably fine with that, though